# Inject Method use in Rspec book, context: Codebreaker game

Tags: ruby, rspec

Hello my questions are to the use of the inject method used in RSpec book with the codebreaker game.  I am having trouble reading and understanding what it is doing.  I have read the explanation of the method at; http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject, but it is still unclear.  Could someone please enlighten a newb?

1)  What does the argument of 0 being passed after the .inject mean?  The first index spot for 0..3 in the range?
2)  I see that count is the accumulator memo value and that index is the index spot, but how is the block being utilized and tied into the next line of code?

3)  Why is the ternary operator being used?

SNIPPET OF THE CODE IN QUESTION:

```
def exact_match_count(guess)
  (0..3).inject(0) do |count, index|
    count + (exact_match?(guess, index) ? 1 : 0)
  en
end

def number_match_count(guess)
  (0..3).inject(0) do |count, index|
    count + (number_match?(guess, index) ? 1 : 0)
  end
end
```

I believe it is paralleled with this example but do not see it.

```
# find the longest word
longest = %w{ cat sheep bear }.inject do |memo, word|
  memo.length > word.length ? memo : word
end

longest                                        #=> "sheep"
```

FULL CODE FOR GREATER CONTEXT:

```
module Codebreaker
  class Game

def initialize(output)
  @output = output
end

def start(secret)
  @secret = secret
  @output.puts 'Welcome to Codebreaker!'
  @output.puts 'Enter guess:'
end

def guess(guess)
  @output.puts '+' *exact_match_count(guess) + '-'*number_match_count(guess)
end

def exact_match?(guess, index)
  guess[index] == @secret[index]
end

def number_match?(guess, index)
  @secret.include?(guess[index]) && !exact_match?(guess, index)
end

def exact_match_count(guess)
  (0..3).inject(0) do |count, index|
    count + (exact_match?(guess, index) ? 1 : 0)
  end
end

def number_match_count(guess)
  (0..3).inject(0) do |count, index|
    count + (number_match?(guess, index) ? 1 : 0)
  end
end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What does the argument of 0 being passed after the .inject mean?
>   The first index spot for 0..3 in the range?

The `0` is the initial accumulator value. If it wasn't present, the first element of the range would be passed as the accumulator value and the second as the index, bypassing the application of the block's logic to the first index.

> 2) I see that count is the accumulator memo value and that index is
>   the index spot, but how is the block being utilized and tied into the
>   next line of code?

The block gets executed for each element of the range. I don't know what you mean by "next line". The block only has one statement in it and the method terminates immediately after the block.

> 3) Why is the ternary operator being used?

Not sure in what sense you're asking "why". It accomplishes the intended logic.

Answer (score 0):

> 3) Why is the ternary operator being used?

If you have been driving through in the RSpec book it's easy to lose track of what's going on at any given point.

When I saw the above answer, questioning your question, my first response way, "It's a fair question, they're taking an integer and treating it like a bool."

At some point I had missed where we stopped pushing integers around and started moving bools.

Bottom line, the ternary operator is being used because it makes sense in the situation.